# Learning HTML and CSS - problems with background, positioning of items and view on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have started trying to code my first website after learning for about 2 days.. and have run into some problems (inevitably):

- When viewing the page from a phone, everything gets moved way out of position
- I can see the home screen absolutely fine on the live server but after importing the files to host the website, the background isn't coming up
- When zooming in/out of the page elements move around

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

The website in question where I have uploaded the home page is: http://btbco.co.uk/

What I've coded in the index.html and styles.css files (in Visual Studio Code) is copied below:

(Please bare in mind I am very much as beginner as you can get and my terminology and knowledge will be **very** limited)

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
img.logo {
  max-width: 31rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 85rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1.hometitle {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}

footer {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 99%;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.home-list {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 21rem;
  left: 88rem;
  color: white;
  width: 25rem;
}

li.homenav {
  color: #ffbd59;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #000000;
  background-color: black;
  border: groove;
  padding-top: 0.1px;
  max-width: 25rem;
  position: static;
}

body {
  background-image: url(/Images/Home\ page.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/Images/Browser logo.png" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0," />
    <meta
      name="keywords"
      content="burgers, beef burgers, halal, halal burgers, food, halal food"
    />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="The new home of fresh juicy burgers. We use halal 100% pure beef in our patties."
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Bun The Burger | The new home of fresh juicy beef burgers</title>
      </head>
  <div class="logo"> 
  
  </div>
    <h1 class="hometitle">
      <em>Bun The Burger &copy;</em>
    </h1>
    <!-- Logo-->
    <a href="http://buntheburger.co.uk">
      <img class="logo" src="images/LOGO.png" alt="Bun The Burgers Logo" />
    </a>
    <!--Navigation Menu-->
    <div class="Navigation"> <nav> 
      
        <ul class="home-list">
          <a href="http://menu.buntheburger.co.uk"><li class="homenav">Menu</li></a>
          <a href="http://order.buntheburger.co.uk"><li class="homenav">Order</li></a>
          <a href="http://aboutus.buntheburger.co.uk"><li class="homenav">About Us</li></a>
          <a href="http://testimonials.buntheburger.co.uk"><li class="homenav">Testimonials</li></a>
          <a href="http://contactus.buntheburger.co.uk"> <li class="homenav">Contact Us</li></a>
        
    </nav>
  </div>
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
      <p>   2022 Bun The Burger © &#x2013; All Rights Reserved</p>
      <p> Home &#8226; Menu &#8226; Order &#8226; About Us &#8226; Contact Us &#8226; Privacy Policy &#8226; Terms and Conditions</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use spaces in file path. Also you structure is not correct. If you view sources on your uploaded HTML it is http://btbco.co.uk/Bun%20The%20Burger/Images/LOGO.png (copy this into browser you see image) but your HTML shows http://buntheburger.co.uk/images/LOGO.png

Comment: Thank you - noted not to use spaces and fixed it as per your instructions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted your `background-positioning` and also, the biggest thing I would suggest when trying to make your site responsive is to stay away from absolute positioning as much as possible. For example, on your `ul` and `logo` you have `left: 88rem`. `88rem` is going to be different on all media devices so on mobile devices (smaller screens) it will be completely out of the screen and will cause overflow on the x-axis. I removed that absolute positioning and added a `container` so that I could use a flexbox on your content. Your content is now responsive without any x-axis overflow. I also adjusted your footer so it was 100 % width of all devices.

Also, you had a few errors which will cause semantic issues later on. You don't have an opening `body` tag and you forgot to close your unordered list `ul`. Be sure to avoid these errors as much as possible in the future, cause they won't accurately affect the live front-end if they are present, which could cause CSS that is unnecessary. This should get you started on a responsive build, however.

Also, I suggest using a good IDE editor that formats your code properly, so these semantic errors can be greatly reduced. For a beginner, I would recommend [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

img.logo {
  max-width: 31rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1.hometitle {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}

footer {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.home-list {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  width: 25rem;
}

li.homenav {
  color: #ffbd59;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #000000;
  background-color: black;
  border: groove;
  padding-top: 0.1px;
  position: static;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/1000/507c8c/fff');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/Images/Browser logo.png" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0," />
      <meta name="keywords" content="burgers, beef burgers, halal, halal burgers, food, halal food" />
      <meta name="description" content="The new home of fresh juicy burgers. We use halal 100% pure beef in our patties." />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <title>Bun The Burger | The new home of fresh juicy beef burgers</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="logo">
            <!-- Logo-->
            <a href="http://buntheburger.co.uk">
            <img class="logo" src="images/LOGO.png" alt="Bun The Burgers Logo" />
            </a>
            <!--Navigation Menu-->
            <div class="Navigation">
               <nav>
                  <ul class="home-list">
                     <a href="http://menu.buntheburger.co.uk">
                        <li class="homenav">Menu</li>
                     </a>
                     <a href="http://order.buntheburger.co.uk">
                        <li class="homenav">Order</li>
                     </a>
                     <a href="http://aboutus.buntheburger.co.uk">
                        <li class="homenav">About Us</li>
                     </a>
                     <a href="http://testimonials.buntheburger.co.uk">
                        <li class="homenav">Testimonials</li>
                     </a>
                     <a href="http://contactus.buntheburger.co.uk">
                        <li class="homenav">Contact Us</li>
                     </a>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
            </div>
         </div>
         <h1 class="hometitle">
            <em>Bun The Burger &copy;</em>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <!--Footer-->
      <footer>
         <p> 2022 Bun The Burger © &#x2013; All Rights Reserved</p>
         <p> Home &#8226; Menu &#8226; Order &#8226; About Us &#8226; Contact Us &#8226; Privacy Policy &#8226; Terms and Conditions</p>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried incorporate everything you mentioned - I had fiddled with the code upon discovering animations, etc. so couldn't just copy & paste it.

However I'm finding that the navigation box is now out of position? Have I gone wrong somewhere with following the code?

Comment: Also, I fiddled with the background earlier so not sure what's caused it but now upon zooming out the background gets repeated, I thought the background-repeat: no-repeat; was supposed to stop that, or am I mistaken?